# Satchmo Gift Certificates. Purchasing multipal gift certificates and only receive one code

Tags: python, django, certificate, satchmo

So I am using Satchmo Store and I have a gift certificate module set up as a way to purchase coupons on my website. However, when I purchase more than 1 on the select quantity page it will only email me one Gift Certificate, not multiple ones according to how many I purchased.

Here is the listener to how the gift certificate is emailed once purchased. Any one have some insight to this?

```
def coupon_notify(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    recipient = instance.purchased_by.email
    buyer = '%s %s' % (instance.purchased_by.first_name, instance.purchased_by.last_name)
    subject = "You Coupon"
    html_content = 'Your code:<br><strong style="font-size:40px; color:#000;">%s</strong>' % (instance.code)
    sender = 'name@email.ca'
    msg = EmailMessage(subject, html_content, sender, [recipient])
    msg.content_subtype = "html"
    msg.send()


def coupon_code_listener():
    save_signals.post_save.connect(coupon_notify,\
        sender=GiftCertificate,dispatch_uid="coupon_notify")
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm far from an expert on the field and have no experience with listeners... but I would say that the listener is called only once because the form is posted/saved only once too. So maybe you should look for the amount of coupons purchased on the model-instance and then go on from there to send multiple mails... or maybe the amount of coupons purchased reflect on how many times you are allowed to use the coupon/code?